# Bash shell operator {1..n} not working when using variables

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on a progress bar, so I need to **print several consecutive** `#` characters. I am using **Bash shell operation**.

This is the case example:

```
$ a=20
$ printf "#%.0s" {1..a}
#$ printf "#%.0s" {1..$a}
#$ printf "#%.0s" {1.."$a"}
#$ printf "#%.0s" {1..20}
####################
```

Note that it is only generated one only `#`, except when using the direct `20` value in the command line. Invoking the `a` variable seems not to work.

I need to do this programmatically, because `20` could be any other number.

What am I missing? Something obvious/stupid?
Thanks you.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-can-i-use-var-in-a-shell-brace-expansion-of-a-sequence

Comment: Try ((a=20)).  I would try it out first before suggesting it, but I am not near a computer.

Comment: printf "#%.0s"  $(seq 1 $a)

Comment: It requires `seq`, but working all right, @fpmurphy1 . Thanks.